# Accessing MySQL Server from IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.5

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, database-connection

I am trying to program a web application using Java JSP, Tomcat 9 and MySQL server on a Windows 10 machine using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.5.
The problem is that I always get the `ClassNotFoundException` when running the following line of code: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

I have followed the official documentation on how to connect to a SQL-server: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2017.1/getting-started-with-datagrip.html

View->Tools Window->Database->+->Data Source->MySQL.

Here is a screenshot of my configuration:
[image]

Please note: I purposefully did not specify a database, since my program cannot assume that the database already exists. It has to check first and create it if it does not. Since the program has never been able to connect to the server, the database has never been created and therefore does not exist. I fear that this might be the source of the problem but pressing "Test Connection" results in a successful connection (as seen in the screenshot).

After some more googling, I manually downloaded the mysql-connector-java-8.0.13 and placed the jar file into the library section of the install directory of IntelliJ. Then I went to File->Project Structure->Libraries->+ and selected the connector. Here is the result:
[image]

IntelliJ now does list the connector under External Libraries.

Yet, the problem still persists.

Please bear in mind that I am new to IntelliJ and that I have little experience using databases with Java. I normally use C++ for that purpose.

UPDATE 1:
To what kind of project: New Project->Java Enterprise->Web Application (with Java 11, Tomcat 9.0.12 and Version 4.0 selected). The rest is, apart from the project name and location, just standard settings.

Comment: IntelliJ’s database tool window has nothing to do with your project, really. What is your project structure? Are you using some build tool, like Maven or Gradle, update the question with more details about your actual project.

Comment: I just updated the question. See bottom.

Comment: How are you actually running your class/application from Intellij?  Are you using a build structure, just a java main class?

Comment: No, there is no main. IntelliJ executes whichever file is called index.jsp. A jsp file is a file combining HTML (optionally also CSS) and Java. This index.jsp file calls a java class responsible for setting up the database.

Comment: I just tried to add the library via Maven. Still getting the error.

Comment: Never mind. I finally found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Like a commenter to my question rightly pointed out, View->Tools Window->Database->+->Data Source->MySQL does not matter to the problem.

Firstly, you have to add the connector as a library. I ended up adding it twice, once as a Java library and once as a maven library. But if you try it, either one should suffice.

The trick is, you also have to add it as an Artifact. In my case, this was pointed out under Problems. IntelliJ also offered to do the adding for me. What I don't know is, if problem points this out right from the start or only after a failed attempted to run the program. No matter what, the problem can be solved by adding the database connector to the Artifacts category under Files->Project->Structure->Artifacts.